# How to assign numbers to values

Tags: r, merge, variable-assignment

I made a mistake/didn't plan well in coding some items before collecting data, and now I have a dataset where the same item has a different number depending on participant. I'd like to assign numbers from 1-500 to each item so that they can be uniquely identified with that number.

I tried `inner_join`, which worked for other variables, but for some reason it ignored the 1-500 values, and they just don't get added to the dataframe.
I also tried to create the variable as a vector or list, and then add it to the existing df, but that results in my data being copied 500 times, for every value, and doesn't help!

for example

```
numbers<-list(1:500)
NewDF <- merge(Memory2, numbers)
```

results in 500 copies of each value and that's not what I'm going for

How can I assign numbers to values otherwise?
Thanks

EDIT: There is more than one instance of each value, so I want to have something like:

```
ITEM VALUE
word1 1
word1 1
word1 1
word2 2
word2 2
word3 3
word3 3
word3 3
word4 4
```

this might be why simply pasting doesn't work

EDIT 2:
ok, `inner_join` worked when the items in the second DF were in a random order instead of ascending or descending, weirdly enough, so this can probably be closed.

Comment: Do you need to change the column name, Then do, `names(Memory2) <- paste(names(Memory2), 1:500, sep="_")`

Comment: Sorry, not sure I got this. Change them to what? When I use my existing column name ("word"), it says:
"argument is not an atomic vector; coercingargument is not an atomic vector; coercingError in word(Memory2) <- paste(word(Memory2), 1:500, sep = "_") : 
  could not find function "word<-" "

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. What do you intend to change in 'Memory2'

Comment: If you need to change a particular colum, then just do `Memory2$particularcolumn <- 1:500`

Comment: No I don't need to change anything, just got confused, but either way I'm getting the error message

Comment: I am confused more than you. YOu haven't showed any example data or expected output, so it is hard to know what is going on